# jquery mobile -- label, input, text in same line

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I've tried much time to put the label, input & text in the same line:

```
Birth Date _________ *
```

how to put the "*" in the same line?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left text"> Birth Date: </div>
  <div class="content">
    <input type="text" id="bdate" name="bdate"  maxlength="8" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">*</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 75px 0 90px; 
    width: 125px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 90px; 
}
.text {
    padding-top: 1.0em;
    padding-bottom: 0.7em;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.right {
    float: left;
}
```

it's also useless to set "float:right" in the CSS .right section.

Anybody helps?

Please do not the way in "jquery", it also doesn't work on "jquery mobile"(1.3.1), thanks a lot!

Comment: Most of those divs are superfluous. You can get rid of all the divs but 'wrapper' and change the Birth Date and * divs to spans.

Comment: try jqm grids or use table.

Comment: Thanks for your remind Stephen, there's really too much divs.
Omar, grids or table are all good solutions, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed a little thing:

```
.content {
    margin: 0 75px 0 90px; 
    width: 125px;{
    float: left;            // Added this row
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 90px; 
}
.right {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Itay!
Does the "content" div can't inherit "float:left" from "wrapper" div?

Comment: @frankz Well we can ask the same question for `.left` and `.right`. If you'll look at [float - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) you'll see `Inherited no`, so that answers your question. You can how ever combine them like this `.wrapper > div { float: left; }`